# My program that use xcb unable to capture keyboard globally

Tags: c, x11, xorg, xcb

I want write a simple window manager, but there is a problem that my program use xcb unable to capture keyboard globally. I know my code is wrong, so can you help me correct it？If you want write a window manager too, please contact me, maybe we can do it together.Thanks.
CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

xcb_connection_t *conn;
xcb_screen_t *screen;
const xcb_setup_t *setup;
xcb_generic_event_t *ev;

void dieout(){
    printf("Die out");
    xcb_disconnect(conn);
    exit(0);
}

void prepare(){
    conn = xcb_connect(NULL,NULL);
    setup = xcb_get_setup(conn);
    screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup).data;
}

int main(){
    prepare();
    xcb_flush(conn);
    while(1){
        ev = xcb_wait_for_event(conn);
        switch(ev->response_type){
            case XCB_KEY_PRESS:
                printf("Keyboard Pressed");
                break;
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

WHAT I DO:

```
gcc main.c -lxcb -lxcb-keysyms
Xephyr +xinerama -screen 500x500 -screen 500x500 -ac :1&
DISPLAY=:1 ./a.out
#press some keys in xephyr
```

OUTPUT:
empty

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: What input do you use or what do you do? What output do you expect? I suggest to add error checking as specified by the documentation, e.g. call ` xcb_connection_has_error()` after `xcb_connect`, check the return value of `xcb_flush`. Check if `xcb_wait_for_event` returns other events.

Comment: Please add the checks as suggested and show the result. Does your program behave differently with `DISPLAY=:0`?